# Understanding Dependency Injection in Generic Repository Implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

**First Implementation:**

```
public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericDal<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly Context _context;

    public GenericRepository(Context context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public void Delete(T entity)
    {
        _context.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

**Second Implementation:**

```
public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericDal<T> where T : class
{
    public void Delete(T entity)
    {
        using var context = new Context();
        context.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

In the first implementation, I'm using Dependency Injection to pass the database context (Context) through the constructor, while in the second implementation, I create a new context internally.

As far as I know, using keyword removes the source without waiting garbage collector which is good, on the other hand, dependency injection implements the Dependency Inversion principle, and this is the application of one of SOLID principles in the code.

Here are my questions about this:

1. Does the first implementation, with Dependency Injection, align more closely with the Dependency Inversion principle?
2. What are the practical implications, particularly in terms of flexibility, testability, and performance, while also considering the SOLID principles.
3. Are there scenarios where one approach is more suitable than the other?

I would appreciate any insights or guidance on the best practices regarding Dependency Injection in this context. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

First off it is worth mentioning that the Generic Repository pattern is completely unnecessary and counter-productive with EF. Entity Framework already implements a generic repository in the form of `DbSet<TEntity>`. When you define a `DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }` in your `DbContext`, you have a generic repository for accessing customers. The `DbContext` itself acts as a Unit of Work.

A common reason developers try and abstract this fact from their solution is that they feel they don't want to couple their solution to Entity Framework, just in case a reason comes up that the need or want to swap EF out for some other DAL. By implementing a Generic Repository around EF, this more often than not forms a self-fulfilling prophecy, resulting in code that is too complex and/or limited and/or slow, justifying a decision to replace it with something else.

The real reason why you should avoid the Generic Repository is that it cripples what EF can bring to your solution. Generic classes are about templating identical behaviour across types. Entities and data operations are not identical. For example, when reading data like search results we don't really need entities, we can use projection (`Select`) to have a query build us an optimized view of data to render. How do we do that with a generic method? How do we sort, paginate, filter data being read in a Generic method when the properties are unique to the type being read? When we want to fetch an actual entity, how do we tell it what properties it should eager load? Is it possible? yes, but it is rather complex code involving passing expressions around. Usually the argument to abstract EF is to isolate code from EF-isms, but implementing this complexity with expressions etc. just serves to leak the EF-isms anyways. For instance callers building an expression to use in a `Where` clause or such still have to adhere to rules about what EF can translate into SQL. As a general rule, don't try and hide EF behind an abstraction. Code that embraces EF as an integral part of its solution will gain far more benefits and  lead to fewer problems that lead to the fear about needing to abstract it in the first place.

To the nitty gritty of your two examples: Injecting a DbContext is generally a better solution than scoping it internally, however it does depend on something taking ownership for the lifetime scope of the `DbConext`. For example, in an ASP.Net MVC/API application, the `DbContext` would be scoped to the web request, meaning at the start of a request, a `DbContext` instance is created, and it is disposed at the end of the request. In other applications like WPF or a Windows Service you would need to manage the lifetime scope of the `DbContext` in a similar way. `DbContext` instances should live only as long as they are needed. When a `DbContext` loads a tracked instance it keeps that instance of data cached. This is good in the short term but gets expensive in the long term as more data gets cached, and leads to stale data scenarios the longer cached copies of rows are held. The `using` block example is as short as a `DbContext` can expect to get, but it is often two short, especially with a Generic Repository pattern. The issue becomes tracking and association. Imagine if you have an Order repository and a Customer repository. When you want to create an Order you associate it with a Customer. So your code looks something like:

```
var customer = CustomerRepository.Find(customerId);
var order = new Order { Customer = customer };
OrderRepository.Create(order);
```

or something similar. If CustomerRepository and OrderRepository scope their own DbContext, this code doesn't work out of the box because the Customer instance fetched by the CustomerRepository is unknown to the new `DbContext` instance created by OrderRepository. When a `DbContext` is handed an instance of an entity it isn't tracking, it treats it as a new record, regardless of whether it has a PK set or not. Working around this behavior needs to be deliberate and is error prone. If they share the same injected `DbContext` instance then it works a bit better since the Customer instance loaded is tracked so when the same DbContext instance goes to save a new Order, it knows the Customer is an existing record.

Without the complexity of adding repositories:

```
var customer = _context.Customers.Single(x => x.CustomerId == customerId);
var order = new Order(/*required fields*/, customer);
_context.Orders.Add(order);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Or if you want a more DDD approach where customers are responsible for the action of adding an Order, such as checking for duplicates etc:

```
var order = new Order(/* required fields */);
var customer = await _context.Customers
    .Include(c => c.Orders)
    .SingleAsync();
var result = customer.AddOrder(order);
if(result.IsSuccessful)
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
else
    // return result message with reason order could not be added.
```

There are cases where you will want code scoping a new `DbContext` instance. Things like auditing or logging are an example. While they certainly can share a `DbContext` instance, these operations might want to be isolated so that they can commit data independently from the main `DbContext` instance. For instance if you want to log something like a failure to a record, the main `DbContext` instance will be "poisoned" by entities that cannot be saved. That `DbContext` cannot save log entries, so it is better if logging code uses its own `DbContext` instance. Cases where you want to parallelize work that saves data is another example where individually scoped contexts are used. `DbContext` is not thread safe so each thread needs to work with a dedicated instance.

Answer (score 0):

> Does the first implementation, with Dependency Injection, align more closely with the Dependency Inversion principle?

Despite that the word *dependency* appears in both *Dependency Injection* (DI) and *Dependency Inversion Principle* (DIP), they're independent (although somewhat related) ideas.

The first code alternative indeed makes use of the Constructor Injection design pattern - the most common DI pattern. Does it also follow the DIP?

We can't really tell from the example, because the DIP is a principle about abstraction:

> Abstractions should not depend upon details. Details should depend upon abstractions.
>
> [...] clients [...] own the abstract interfaces
>
> - [APPP](https://blog.ploeh.dk/ref/appp)

Is that the case here? I can't tell from the OP. Does the `Delete` method exist on `IGenericDal<T>` because client code needs it, or because the implementation is able to provide that method?

In general, I'm highly sceptical of any interface or base class that exposes or makes use of Entity Framework (EF) (or any other ORM) or 'entity classes'. Such types tend to automatically violate the DIP, which also requires that

> High-level modules should not depend on low-level modules. Both should depend on abstractions.

Given that the `T` in the `Delete` method in practice is going to be an 'entity class', and that entity classes have all sorts of constraints placed on them, I consider such classes as low-level modules. Therefore the high-level module (`IGenericDal<T>`) de facto depends on a low-level module (the entity classes, or EF itself). Thus, I consider that a DIP violation.